# Generator returned from function completes prematurely

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I have following piece of code to multiplex blocking generators:

```
import datetime
import time
import queue
import threading


def blocking1():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        result = "Block1: {}".format(datetime.datetime.now())
        yield result


def blocking2():
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        result = "Block2: {}".format(datetime.datetime.now())
        yield result


def multiplex(generators):
    if len(generators) == 1:
        return generators[0]
    elif len(generators) > 1:
        q = queue.Queue()

        def run_one(src):
            for e in src: q.put(e)

        def run_all():
            threads = []
            for src in generators:
                t = threading.Thread(target=run_one, args=(src,))
                t.start()
                threads.append(t)
            for t in threads: t.join()
            q.put(StopIteration)

        threading.Thread(target=run_all).start()
        while True:
            e = q.get()
            if e is StopIteration:
                return
            yield e
    else:
        return []


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # tasks = [("map1: {}".format(e) for e in blocking1()), ("map2: {}".format(e) for e in blocking2())]
    tasks = [("map1: {}".format(e) for e in blocking1())]
    for e in multiplex(tasks):
        print(e)
```

I wanted to be clever and in case there is only one generator, don't do any thread spawning. Just return this single generator (after all the types still match)

However it doesn't work like that.
The program immediately terminates (like this is empty generator)

What's funny is that following works (the `map1...` output is displayed):

```
import datetime
import time
import queue
import threading


def blocking1():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        result = "Block1: {}".format(datetime.datetime.now())
        yield result


def blocking2():
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        result = "Block2: {}".format(datetime.datetime.now())
        yield result


def multiplex(generators):
    if len(generators) == 1:
        return generators[0]
    else:
        return []


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # tasks = [("map1: {}".format(e) for e in blocking1()), ("map2: {}".format(e) for e in blocking2())]
    tasks = [("map1: {}".format(e) for e in blocking1())]
    for e in multiplex(tasks):
        print(e)
```

Where the difference is only in removal of `elif` part...

Could someone help me understand what is going on please?
I'm using Python 3.5.3

Comment: can you print `len(generators)` in your function?

Comment: It's `1`, why should it be different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't (usefully) return a value from a function that also does a `yield` anywhere in its body (even if `return` and `yield`s occur in separate blocks of code that can never run during the same execution of the function). If you have a `yield` anywhere in the function, you are making a generator function rather than a normal one.

A good fix for this is to `yield from` your lone generator if you're only given one:

```
def multiplex(generators):
    if len(generators) == 1:
        yield from generators[0] # because this is a generator function, we need to yield here
    elif len(generators) > 1:
        ... # there's a yield in here causing the whole thing to be a generator function!
```

Comment: Thank you but I have the same comment, why cutting the elif part also makes it work ?

Comment: yes! python parser decides if a function is a generator or not by just parsing it, even if the statements aren't reached. This answer explains why (and provides a fix, like the other answer but at least this answer explains why :))

Comment: If you cut the body of the `elif` block, you're cutting the only `yield` statement, so the function gets compiled as a normal function rather than a generator function.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're *returning* a generator, instead of iterating over it.

Replace

```
return generators[0]
```

with

```
yield from generators[0]
```

Comment: Yes the `yield from` works. But why `return generators[0]` also works when there is no `elif...` part?